# Расстояние между двумя точками в км

Tags: mysql

Получаю от гугла координаты точки в виде LatLng, в таком же виде на сервере есть таблица с множеством строк с  полями lat, lon. Нужно выбрать из таблицы только те, которые находятся в радиусе 10 км от заданной точки.

```
SELECT *FROM us WHERE ...
```

какое тут условие сделать? 
вот есть алгоритм на пхп, но мне нужно сделать это средствами mysql

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

нашел. если кому-то пригодится вот в км

```
 SELECT uid, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(50.280848) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians(30.445011) ) + sin( radians(50.280848) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM users HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```